# GIT: problem when i'am type $ git push -u origin main

Tags: github, git-bash

remote: Permission to 17ekspor/17ekspor.git denied to icakstore69.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/17ekspor/17ekspor.git/': The request
ed URL returned error: 403

Comment: Have you tried to push with your username and password? If that's the case [password-based authentication has been removed](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls). I suggest you to rather use ssh.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.